# How to store data after 24 hours in flutter? / How to update UI after some time when app is closed/killed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am making an app with **flutter**. I want to store data after 24 hours and update UI in app.
I try with `Timer.periodic()` but it does not count the time when app is close. It only works when the application is open.

Is it possible to execute a function after a specific time even if the app is closed?

Here is my current code:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() async{
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    switch(sdDaily){
      case 'StoreDataDaily':
       storeData.storeDailyData();
        break;
      default:
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

```dart
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory directory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  print(directory.path);
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Hive.initFlutter(directory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(WaterAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(WeekAdapter());
  Get.put(UserController());
  Get.put(WaterController());
  await Hive.openBox<User>('data');
  await Hive.openBox<Water>('water_data');
  await Hive.openBox<Week>('week_data');
  await notificationPlugin.showNotification();
  await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  var uniqueId = DateTime.now().second.toString();
  var userBox = Hive.box<User>('data');
  if(userBox.get(0)?.status == 1){
    await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(uniqueId, sdDaily,);
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use : [flutter_background_service.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to execute background services and it'll also help you sending a custom notification when you are actually going to store that data later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase cloud funcitons to do schedule tasks or whatever you want to do even if app is closed or killed.